# Where should I store my CSV files for Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

Even though I copied the CSV inside the docker, whenever I try to load it, I get an error that says "file not found".

Is there a specific directory in which I need to store the CSV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to save the file in the root folder of the Docker container. You should run `docker cp my_csv.csv <container_id>:my_csv.csv` to copy it into the Docker container.

After that CSV file is then loaded from "`/my_csv.csv`".